# show time in numeric updown ajax control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How to format a AJAX NumericUpDown to behave it as a TimeUpDown control in ASP.NET Web page. Time format will be 12:00:00 AM.  I need the Web equivalent of the following control
[image]

Comment: Why ajax? Are you planning on posting back to the server with each change of the control? What is wrong with simple "jax"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a minute or two spent on googling and here's the result: [.NET Time Picker Control](http://www.michaelkbell.com/TimePicker/)

Comment: Its an awesome control. Well.. But when I set custom images for up/down buttons, it arises run errors. How can I specify custom images, I set like ButtonSettings-DownImageURL="images/arrow_down.gif"